# How to handle exception on remote views in Android (custom widgets or custom notifications)?

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

During our attempts to solve a problem that we encountered with exceptions on remote views in Android (on custom widgets and notifications) on users' devices I found the RemoteViews.ActionException object which is a nested class in the RemoteViews object but it's not clear how to use it.

Any best practices we should take when handling exceptions that occur in remote views?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the exception in our app occurred after an update of our app on the user's device. when a user clicked on a notification that was created by the  **previous version** (the one before the upgrade).

We decided that on our app startup after an upgrade - we'll remove all notifications (in our case it makes sense).